# SpEL refactoring in @Value (encrypted property)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

I have a *Spring Security* configuration where I have to use encrypted properties. I have utility static method `PasswordUtil.decode()` by which I can decode a property for the further usage.

Following solution works, but the particular *SpEL* looks quite ugly to me. So, my question: **Is it possible to refactor given *SpEL* expression to something nicer/shorter/idiomatic?**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("#{T(my.package.PasswordUtil).decode('${signkey.password}')}")
    private String signKeyPassword;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can register a custom SpEL Resolver Function [as you can see in the Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-functions). What that means is that you can create a custom SpEL keyword that would resolve in your custom code underneath also supporting inputs.

In other words you'll be able to write instead of:

```
@Value("#{T(my.package.PasswordUtil).decode('${signkey.password}')}")
private String signKeyPassword;
```

the below where your custom SpEL keyword is **mydecode**:

```
@Value("#{ #mydecode( '${signkey.password}' ) }")
String signKeyPassword;
```

This option: 1) significantly reduces the SpEL string literal, 2) gives you the chance to pick up a name that makes sense in your domain and 3) as it is essentially a method call it can be reused with different inputs in different @Value SpEL injections.

Below a working example. Note that it's not Spring Security specific (not using it) neither Spring Boot specific (using it):

**The POM file**

Got this autogenerated from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) not having any components added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The main class **DemoApplication**:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args).getBean(SecurityConfiguration.class);

        System.out.println(securityConfiguration.getSignKeyPassword());
    }

    @Bean
    MyCustomSpELFunctionRegister customSpelFunctionProvider() {
        return new MyCustomSpELFunctionRegister();
    }
}
```

**The SecurityConfiguration:**

As mentioned Spring Security agnostic. It is using the custom SpEL keyword resolver.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("#{ #mydecode( '${signkey.password}' ) }")
    String signKeyPassword;

    public String getSignKeyPassword() {
        return signKeyPassword;
    }
}
```

**The MyCustomSpELDecoderFunction**

This is the class where you'll hide your Utils static method that does the work

```
package com.example.demo;

public abstract class MyCustomSpELDecoderFunction {

    //needs to be public
    //alternative use interface with defined static method
    public static String mydecode(String encrypted) {
        return "myutils decrypt";
    }
}
```

**The MyCustomSpELFunctionRegister class**

This is the glue code that connects your custom SpEL keyword to your Utils class. It implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor to perform the registration before any bean gets created thus halting the @Value injection.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class MyCustomSpELFunctionRegister implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        beanFactory.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver() {
            @Override
            protected void customizeEvaluationContext(StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext) {
                try {

                    //here we register all functions
                    standardEvaluationContext.registerFunction("mydecode", MyCustomSpELDecoderFunction.class.getMethod("mydecode", new Class[] { String.class }));

                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible as `@Value` may be used as meta annotation:

Option 1: Override @Value value:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Value("")
public @interface SignKeyPassword {

    @AliasFor(annotation=Value.class, attribute="value")
    String value() default "#{T(my.package.PasswordUtil).decode('${signkey.password}')}";

}
```

Option 2: Separate annotation for each property:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Value("#{T(my.package.PasswordUtil).decode('${signkey.password}')}")
public @interface SignKeyPassword {
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @SignKeyPassword
    private String signKeyPassword;

}
```

Option 3: Implement `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor` to define own injection login

Comment: That looks better, but like this, it can be used for single property only. Is it possible to have it more general? I have more than one encrypted property.

Comment: I see, probably you're looking for the way to specify property name in annotation and to inject corresponding decoded value. As far as I'm aware, it is not possible. I see 3 workarounds here: 1. Override @Value value from your custom annotation (updated answer); 2. For each property create separate annotation; 3. Implement InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor for custom injection strategy: you can create one generic annotation and inject corresponding value depending on its argument

Comment: I like the 1) option (`@Value` value overriding). I'm just thinking if it's better than bean resolving/referencing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [@dimitrisli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185723/dimitrisli)'s *SpEL* function could be a bean reference as described in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-bean-references). This looks more comprehensible to me, because the bean is defined in the same `@Configuration`. (Plus, the decrypting method doesn't have to be `static`.)

I'm just wondering if the bean resolving could be done in simpler way.

**Bean resolving**

```java
public class PassportUtilResolver implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver() {

            @Override
            protected void customizeEvaluationContext(StandardEvaluationContext evalContext) {
                evalContext.setBeanResolver(new BeanResolver() {

                    @Override
                    public Object resolve(EvaluationContext context, String beanName) throws AccessException {
                        if ("passwordUtil".equals(beanName)) {
                            return new PasswordUtil();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("#{@passwordUtil.decode('${regis.saml.signkey.password}')}")
    private String signKeyPassword;

    @Bean
    public PasswordUtil passwordUtil() {
        return new PasswordUtil();
    }

}
```